# How to assign a single variable to a specific line in python?

Tags: python

I was not clear enough in my last question, and so I'll explain my question more this time.

I am creating 2 separate programs, where the first one will create a text file with 2 generated numbers, one on line 1 and the second on line 2.

Basically I saved it like this:

In this example I'm not generating numbers, just assigning them quickly.

```
a = 15
b = 16
saving = open('filename.txt', "w")
saving.write(a+"\n")
saving.write(b+"\n")
saving.close()
```

Then I opened it on the next one:

```
opening = open('filename.txt', "w")
a = opening.read()
opening.close()
print(a) #This will print the whole document, but I need each line to be differnet
```

Now I got the whole file loaded into 'a', but I need it split up, which is something that i have not got a clue on how to do. I don't believe creating a list will help, as I need each number (Variables a and b from program 1) to be different variables in program 2. The reason I need them as 2 separate variables is because I need to divide it by a different number. If I do need to do a list, please say. I tried finding an answer for about an hour in total, though I couldn't find anything.

The reason I can't post the whole program is because I haven't got access to it from here, and no, this is not cheating as we are free to research and ask questions outside the classroom, if someone wonders about that after looking at my previous question.

If you need more info please put it in a comment and I'll respond ASAP.

Comment: Are you sure `15 + '\n'` actually worked?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. It adds 15 than starts a new line, to which the next number is added.

Comment: `15 + '\n'` is a `TypeError`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to make it a string. Just change a and b to: a = str(15) and b = str(16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opening = open('filename.txt') # "w" is not necessary since you're opening it read-only
a = [b.split() for b in opening.readlines()] # create a list of each line and strip the newline "\n" character

print(a[0]) # print first line
print(a[1]) # print second line
```

Comment: This isn't bad, though I'm unable to add the two values together, which is something I need to do. Tried changing them into integers but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the answer to this question through some more research into lists.

Basically what I had to do was add this:

    c1, c2 = a <newline>
    c1 = str(c1) <newline>
    c1 = c1.strip("['") <newline>
    c1 = c1.strip("']") <newline>
    print(c1) <newline>

And all that gave me a single number which I can turn into an integer and divide, multiply, etc.